# AWS Beanstalk and SES authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a node.js application running via beanstalk.  I want to send email using the "Simple Email Serivce" from AWS.

In my app I need to authenticate with SES, so;

```
const ses = new aws.SES({
  accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: AWS_SES_REGION
})
```

But specifying my key here again seems ugly. Do I have to specify the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey here again in my application, or is there a smarter way to set this up with Beanstalk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to assign an IAM Instance Profile to the EC2 instances in your Elastic Beanstalk environment. Then your code can simply be:

```
const ses = new aws.SES({
  region: AWS_SES_REGION
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not want to specify those keys in your code. EC2 supports the use of a IAM Profile. So the AWS sdk that is installed in the instance will work out the credentials(effectively) for you. Just make sure you assign an Role to your Elastica Beanstalk Enviornment that has the ability to use SES.

You can read more [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html#using-features.managing.ec2.profile).

Comment: This is correct, but not sure why you are talking about Lambda when the question is about Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Me either.. not enough coffee or cross circuits with another problem rattling around in my head. I will edit this.  Thanks for the catch @mark